# Is it safe for final binary to leave anti-virus running while compiling?

Tags: c++, compilation

I was required to use Microsoft Windows to build Windows binaries of an open project code, while the output i got works, i'm wondering if aggressive Anti-Malware may affect the final binary in a bad way (unexpected errors during compilation, during use of the compiled binary or not-running-at-all binary).

Question raised in my head after seeing the Anti-Malware service increase UC time consumption specifically when compiling, consuming up to 600% more UC it would usually when working on the computer.

Comment: I've seen AV force a build failure due to file locks etc, but I'm not sure it would cause a bad exe...

Comment: @John3136 I've seen it slow things down enormously; I've also had problems with encryption or the antivirus totally destroying files, converting source files into something that isn't text, without modifying the time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

If your binary happen to cause a false positive, the AV software will 
indeed try to modify it, but not silently. So yes, its safe, if there's a 
problem, you will know about it.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the only thing antivirus software does is deleting files and not modifying them. You should be notified when a file is deleted. You should still check if you get notified by the antivirus software during compile time. If you are not notified by the anti virus software during compile time, you can expect your  program to be correctly compiled. If you run your program after compilation, the situation might look different. Your program can be wrongly detected by his behavior and be deleted when it is executed. However your program has already been compiled when it is executed.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt the anti-virus software was reacting to the intermediate files created during compilation and linking.  In a large project, they can be quite big and would take a fair amount of processing to filter through looking for trouble.

If you have any doubt, you don't have to use Windows.  You can use [`wine`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) on Linux to run MSVC safely and with no AV software.  At the minimum you could compare (as in `diff`) the products of a Linux-based build with those on Windows to gain confidence that all is as it should be.

Comment: Have you tried running MSVC on Wine? The last few versions of both the VC redist and Visual Studio have had "Garbage" rating on WineHq and last I tried it wouldn't even install. If, however, you have some tips to get it running I would be very interested.

For my own purposes it would be quite sufficient to run MSBuild alone, without the visual studio interface.

Comment: @Agentlien:  I tried it 4+ years ago, and VS 2008 was a pain to install.  I ended up installing into a Windows virtual machine and then copying all the files to Linux.  I then ran the non-gui backend under wine to compile.  It never seemed all that solid, but there was reason to believe the wine folks would improve that.  If it is *still* garbage support, then I guess that hope was misplaced.